# How to cref a static constructor in C# xml comments?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know the syntax for referencing a static constructor in the "cref" attribute of an xml comment?

I can reference a normal constructor, as shown.

```
public class MyType 
{
    ///<permission cref="??">...</permission>
    static MyType()
    {
    }

    ///<permission cref="MyType()">...</permission>
    public MyType()
    {
    }
}
```

I've tried variations on "cctor", which is how the static method appears in the compiled XML documentation. I've also tried "static MyType()".

Comment: It may not be possible as it is unclear how would one write a human-readable string reference to a static ctor.

Comment: There's good info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/cref-attribute, but nothing on static constructors.  Reading the XML that gets produced, my guess is that it would be formatted as `<member name="M:TestNamespace.TestClass.#cctor">` in the output XML.  But again, I don't know how you'd produce it.  None of my guesses worked

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/235 is about <> vs {}, but provides an interesting starting point and a reference to CrefCompletionProvider.cs. CrefTests.cs provides a dizzying array of test cases and seems to imply that a cref to a static constructor in a static class is OK. In CrefCompletionProvider.GetQualifiedSymbols, we see a reference an INamedTypeSymbol's InstanceConstructors property (not the Constructors property - which would seem to depart from CrefTests' implication that a static constructor is OK in a static class.  Maybe).  But I feel like I've only scratched the surface.